# Reading from DCIM Camera folder not working

Tags: java, android, android-camera

**SOLVED**

I was using a byte for a int return type and also casting in the wrong moment, see my answer.

**Original question**

Is it allowed to read the files in the folder DCIM/Camera ? I've tried to read and write in lots of places in the external storage and it works, except reading the pictures taken from that folder (I've been able to write).

May be its a problem with my installation of eclipse not compiling the latest version of the sources, but I'm like crazy right now trying to figure out. I've tried removing and adding again the permissions WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE with no luck. May be its supposed to be done with other way of access I don't know because I never tried to read those pictures.

The picture I'm trying to read is exactly 7900 bytes long taken with the virtual camera from genymotion. When I read it, I either only get 4 bytes or 0 (reach end of file), but not a single exception or error on logcat.

This code runs ok in a test suite for any location except those pictures in DCIM/Camera

```
public void testReadCamera() throws IOException {
        File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(dir, "Camera/IMG_20140623_125853.jpg"));
        ArrayList<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
        byte b = 0;
        while((b = (byte) is.read()) != -1) {
            bytes.add(b);
        }
        byte[] data = new byte[bytes.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < bytes.size(); i++){
            data[i] = bytes.get(i);
        }

        assertEquals(7900, data.length);

}
```

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.adyrsoft.pictures.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="com.adyrsoft.pictures" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours smashing my head against the screen I've seen the problem. I was using the wrong data type and casting at the wrong time. Too much time coding, so little focus. Some fresh air and a second pair of eyes helped to discover the goof :)

```
public void testReadCamera() throws IOException {
        File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(dir, "Camera/IMG_20140623_125853.jpg"));
        ArrayList<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
        int b = 0; // This has to be an int, return type of FileInputStream.read() is int
        while((b = is.read()) != -1) { // I was casting to byte here... I still wonder why myself...
            bytes.add((byte)b); //Here is where the cast should have been.
        }
        byte[] data = new byte[bytes.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < bytes.size(); i++){
            data[i] = bytes.get(i);
        }

        assertEquals(file.length(), data.length); // Also...

}
```